# SwiftUI modals in Xcode Beta 6?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode11

Previously in SwiftUI (Xcode Beta 5), a modal worked like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var modalIsPresented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {

            self.modalIsPresented = true

        }) {

            Text("Show modal")

        }

        .sheet(isPresented: $modalIsPresented, content: {

            ModalView()

        })

    }

}

struct ModalView: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {

        Button(action: {

            self.presentationMode.value.dismiss()

        }) {

            Text("Hide modal")

        }

    }

}
```

But now in Xcode Beta 6, I cannot find a way to dismiss a modal. There no longer is a `value` property of `presentationMode`, and the other properties don't seem to have any useful methods I can use.

How do you dismiss a SwiftUI modal in Xcode Beta 6?

Comment: Have you tried passing in `$modalIsPresented` and setting that to false?

Comment: Thanks @Fabian - can you post it as an answer please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using ***wrappedValue*** instead of ***value*** seems to work in Xcode Beta 6:

```
self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can dimiss `.sheet`, `.popover`, `.actionSheet` by passing in the binding that controls it's showing, here `$modalIsPresented` and set it to false inside to programmatically dismiss it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to check this:

```
.presentation(showModal ? Modal(Text("Modal screen"), onDismiss: {
self.showModal.toggle()
}) : nil)
```

The default modal presentation doesn't prove any visual way for the user to close the modal, but as of iOS 13 the user can swipe down the view to make it disappear.

In detail: https://alejandromp.com/blog/2019/06/24/improving-swiftui-modal-presentation-api/